# How to install Prerequisites before installation of a msi?? Can have a complete example for the beginners in WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I need some prerequisites to be installed before my product installation:

1. .NET Framework 4.0
2. SQL Express
3. Microsoft Report Viewer
4. RGQ Export

I do have all these Prerequisites in a folder in Solution but When I mention these in File-source then it just copy all the Prerequisites in program file folder, but I need to install these after license agreement dialog.

Comment: Instead, consider a [WiX Bootstrapper](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/node/76).

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Bootstrap Installation with an single MSI possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927736/net-bootstrap-installation-with-an-single-msi-possible)