# .NET Bootstrap Installation with an single MSI possible?

Tags: .net, wix

I've written an Installer for installing my .NET application. Now I'd like to pre install .NET Framework if necessary. That is not the big deal. The big deal is, there have to be a single MSI without an EXE as a bootstrapper. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain this restriction, especially in view of the fact that the .NET Framework installer is an EXE, is a bootstrapper, and installs many MSIs? Also, does your installer put any assemblies in the .NET 4 CLR GAC (in other words needs .NET 4.x installed as an installation prerequisite)?

Comment: I need an MSI without an EXE to get deploy it over GPO. The requrement is: If .NET Framework isn't installed, install it please. This is just possible with an bootstrapper (EXE).

Comment: Microsoft installs .NET through WSUS. There are wrapper tricks to use GPO. [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a good place to find the least hackish of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer has a couple of mutexs at play here that prevent this.  The first enforces one execute sequence per machine and the second enforces one UI sequence per process.

It is technically possible to have a custom action in the UI sequence spawn a new process and install .NET in that context.  However, this is not a best practice and you'll lose the ability to install your MSI silently.  The best you would  be able to do is a /QR  (Reduced UI) installation.

I feel your pain.  What I've been doing lately (wherever possible)  is target my .NET application for .NET 2.0 and provide an app.config that says CLR 4.0 is supported and to use legacy activation.  This gives me an app targeted for the least common denominator and beyond.  I then put an launch condition in my MSI that checks for .NET 2.0 or greater.

Basically, I feel that Windows XP / Server 2003 is a dinosaur and if a customer still wants to run it they can install .NET themselves.  Windows Vista and beyond has .NET 3.0 or greater.

Comment: This workaround will not work for me. I need to have 4.5. This is really stupid but I can understand why there is just a single sequence. There should be a pause command for a running sequence :-)

Comment: Originally they had a concept of nested/concurrent installations.  You could install multiple MSIs in a single context.  This proved to be disastrous (MSDE slammer worm) and they deprecated it.  There is also a concept of MSI chaining starting in MSI 4.5 but again a catch 22 if you don't already have MSI 4.5.  Also it won't work with .NET because the  framework install is a setup.exe wrapper that chains multiple packages.

Comment: Also an accepted answer would be appreciated as I did answer the question of whether it's possible or not.  Since you are using WiX I suggest you look at Burn to bootstrap .NET.